# Change the value of an XML tag using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, xml

So I have an XML file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.aem</groupId>
        <version>6.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

I want to update the value of `version` to a new value

```
        <version>6.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

but I want to ensure it is updated only in this `<parent>` section, not anywhere else in the file. Is that possible using bash?

Sadly I cannot use `xmlstarlet` as it is not included in the container.

Comment: Can you describe at what other places in the XML tree the `version` tag can occur? How is the location of the tag where you _want_ it to be modified characterized? Is it the only `version` tag inside a `parent` tag? Or are there multiple instances of this, and we have to look at a specific `artifactId` or another attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside that the XML fragment isn't properly formed (you've missed a trailing `</project>` element closing) and fixing that, the correct answer is that you should use an XML parser to parse and edit XML.

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '/_:project/_:parent/_:version' --value '6.5.0-SNAPSHOT' pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test.aem</groupId>
    <version>6.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

The `_:` prefix to each element name is a required wildcard because you're in a separate namespace (`xmlns=...`).

You can of course write the output to a temporary file and then replace the original with the result. Or use `xmlstarlet edit --inplace` if you are absolutely sure you are making a valid edit.

Comment: It is just a snippet from the whole code.I cannot use xmlstarlet, as it is not included in the container

Comment: @Alfador it's the right tool for the job. Perhaps you can add it to the container

Comment: I understand, I will mark this as an answer then and see how to get the tool going

Answer (score 1):

Another option to explore is python, in case the xmlstarlet utility is not present.

We use the `etree` module to traverse the XML hierarchy and modify the version.

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#> unpack command line arguments
new_ver,xml_file = sys.argv[1:]

#> 
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

#> traverse,selec, & modify the desired
#> node using XPath expressions
for e in root.findall("./parent/version"):
  e.text = new_ver

# save changes
tree.write(xml_file)
' "6.5.0-SNAPSHOT" input.xml
```